# Proof that each eigenvalue of $e^X$ is the exponential of an eigenvalue of $X$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading the following post and I am not sure why we need to go through all 5 steps as stated in the selected answer:

[Each eigenvalue of $e^X$ is the exponential of an eigenvalue of $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498836/each-eigenvalue-of-ex-is-the-exponential-of-an-eigenvalue-of-x)

We know that every matrix $X$ has a JCF and we have the property if: $X = P^{-1}AP$ where $A$ is the Jordan matrix, then $e^X = P^{-1}e^AP$ and since taking the exponent of a jordan matrix is still upper diagonal and there is actually an explicit formula for how to do this, one can just read of the diagonal entries and see that every eigenvalue of $e^{X}$ is of the form $e^{\sigma({X})}$
Is that correct?

Comment: I assume you’re talking over $\mathbb{C}$? Otherwise not all matrices have a JCF. But yes, indeed that argument works, but you are just swapping one type of algebraic argument for another.

Comment: Yes this is over C. That statement that eigenvalue of e^X is e to the eigenvalue of X would not be true if we were only talking about matrix over the reals correct?

Comment: Correct; over $\mathbb R$, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-\pi\\\pi&0\end{bmatrix}$ has no eigenvalues, but its exponential $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $-1$.