# Relation between eigenvalues of matrix $A$ and $e^{tA}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume that $A$ is a matrix and
$$e^{tA}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tA)^n}{n!}$$

In my research, I need to know if there is any relation between eigenvalues of $A$ and $e^{tA}$?

I would be so thankful if you give me an idea about it or introduce a reference to study it.

Comment: This question has been answered here before: the eigenvalues of $e^{tA}$ are the $e^{\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $tA$. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498836/each-eigenvalue-of-ex-is-the-exponential-of-an-eigenvalue-of-x